# selenium server standalone: unable to create a new session with vagrant in headless mode

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, vagrant, geckodriver

I am trying to run the selenium server standalone **in a vagrant box**, with the following command:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
```

When I click the 'create session' button at `http://lab.local:4444/wd/hub/static/resource/hub.html` from my **host web browser**. I get a `unable to create a new session` error message.

I ask to create a firefox browser session for which I get the driver located in `/usr/local/bin/geckodriver`.

Firefox has been installed on the vagrant box with `sudo apt install firefox-esr`.

Error log detail:

```
14:52:04.485 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292'
14:52:04.486 INFO [GridLauncherV3$1.launch] - Launching a standalone Selenium Server on port 4444
2018-08-09 14:52:04.564:INFO::main: Logging initialized @312ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
14:52:04.757 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444
14:52:15.563 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
  "browserName": "firefox"
}
14:52:15.568 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
1533819135611   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
1533819135614   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:25541
1533819135880   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.yuusnpGo8Gw6"
1533819136508   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
```

When I run the same executable directly from my host, I get no error and the firefox session is created with success.

I try to run a X server, `Xvfb` as follow but this does not change anything:

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x16 &
export DISPLAY=:1
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.13.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after switching to [selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar](https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=3.3/) with [geckodriver 0.14.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.14.0). Sessions are created with success with this configuration.

[source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3630#issuecomment-285640265).

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question. Did you mean that you needed to switch to the mentioned versions and everything is fine with running sessions in a vagrant box in headless mode?

Comment: yes this is exactly what it means. After switching to the given versions, everything is fine.